# ajaxForm plugin submits on any <button> clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

Take a look at this

http://jsbin.com/goyokir/edit?html,output

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
        alert("Form was submitted"); 
    }); 

  $('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //if removed, it acts as submit button
    $('body').append('regular clicked!<br>');
  });
});
```

My problem is that my form has some `<button>`'s in it and when clicked they act as submit buttons for some strange reason. I can use `preventDefault` to fix that but the other problem is that when your **focus on an input and press enter** it triggers the first `<button>` it finds, not the `<input type='submit'>`

I tried to look at the [plugin's source](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js) and fix it but it's beyond me. `captureSubmittingElement` seems to be just fine to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `button` inside a form acts as a submit button by default

Use `type="button"` to prevent a `button` from acting as a form submission button.

```
<button type="button">Regular &lt;Button&gt; 1</button><br>
<button type="button">Regular &lt;Button&gt; 2</button><br>
<input type="submit" value="Input Submit button" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
<button type="button"></button>.
```

Demo'd here: http://jsbin.com/xabuzukehe/1/edit?html,output

Comment: This answer totally helped me! Thanks! If I could upvote twice I would do it!

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change your button to type button,the default is type submit

```
<button type="button">Regular &lt;Button&gt; 1</button>
```